# C++ derived class call base class method give segmentation fault

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a base class and derived class similar to following:

```
#include "Sprite.h"
class Base{
  private:
    int X; //location
    Sprite* sprite;
  public:
    Base(Sprite* sprite){
        sprite = new Sprite(some parameter);
   }
    int getLocation(){
           return X;
    }
    int getWidth(){
         return sprite->getWidth();
    }
}


 class Derived : public Base{
    private:
      Sprite* sprite;  // here I have to redefine it in constructor
    public:
      Derived(Sprite* sprite);  // it's different that base constructor
 { sprite = new Sprite(some parameter);
   sprite->setPriperty(some parameter);
}
 }
```

When I called Derived::getLocation() from other place, there is no error. But when I called the Derived::getWidth(), it gave me segmentation fault. I have to copy the same code from base class(i.e copy the code of the getWidth into the derived class) in order to avoid the fault. I also tried to use "using Base::getWidth;", but still, gave me segmentation fault. It seems that if the base class method contains pointers t

Comment: "...there is no error" - that you know of. Define some sanity in this. Is there supposed to be **two** `Sprite` instances being managed here? One pointed to by `Base::sprite` and another by `Derived::sprite` ? If not, then you're hosting one-too-many `Sprite*`. And *please*, include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Why do they both have a different Sprite* with the same name?

Comment: There is only one Sprite class. However, in the derived class, after I initialize the private sprite member, I have to set some extra property using sprite's method. So the constructor is different than base class. Thus I have to declare it in derived class.

Comment: Post some of your constructor for Derived. We might be able to help with that.

Comment: I posted the code. If still not enough, I will go home to get more code

Comment: Could you please give us an compiling piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all - what is a segmentation fault? It's something simmilar to a `NullPointerException` in Java or a `NullReferenceException` in C#. It happens when you try to access non allocated memory.

Why is this happening? You forgot to allocate memory for the `sprite` pointer, so it's pointing at some not precised memory chunk. You should initialize it in your constructor by using the `new` operator like this:

```
Base::Base(Sprite* sprite) {
    this->sprite = new Sprite(sprite);
}
```

If you like to live dangerously you could also do the following:

```
Base::Base(Sprite* sprite) {
    this->sprite = sprite;
}
```

But it's not safe, because the sprite could be allocated on the stack, so code like this could wreck havoc to your program causing undefined behavior:

```
Base * getBase() {
    Sprite sprite;
    //some code operating on sprite
    return new Base(&sprite);
}
```

It's hazardous, because after exiting the `getBase` function there is no `sprite` anymore in the memory.

**Update:**

So basically what I concluded from you comments is that you don't call the  proper constructor of your `Base` class. Your `Derived` constructor should look like this:

```
Derived(Sprite* sprite): Base(sprite) {
   ...
}
```

If you don't do this you do not set the value of `sprite` for your base class. Your `sprite` field of your derived class is just shadowing the `sprite` field of your `Base` class. It's like:

```
int i = 0;
void fun() {
    int i = 20;
}
```

In the example the global `i` did not change, because it was shadowed.

Your code works after duplicating the `getWidth()` method in the `Derived` class, because it was accessing then the `sprite` field of your `Derived` class. To be clear - without overriding the method `getWidth()` is accessing the `sprite` field of the `Base` class, when you override it it accesses the field of the `Derived` class.

Comment: I used the new keyword to initialize the pointer, please see the updated code. everything works fine if I duplicate he code of base class in derived class.

Comment: The getWidth method. If I copy it in the derived class, everything works fine. But I thought I dont need to do it because.of inherence

Comment: So does it mean  if I override the private member of base class, I have to override any method that calls that.private member as well? I think this probably why I have to copy the code into derived class

Comment: It means that there is nothing like overriding private members - you are just shadowing the field from the base class. You simply did not initialize the field in the base class, but you initialized the one of your derived class. Fields don't behave polimorphic, so the `Base::getWidth()` method is accessing the `sprite` field which is located in the `Base` class while only the field of the `Derived` class is initialized. If you want to initialize the field in the `Base` class you have to call the constructor in the initialization list of the `Derived` class, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably forgetting to set your `sprite` member variable inside your constructor. Do something like this: `Base(Sprite * s): sprite(s) {}` or `Base(Sprite * s) { this->sprite = s; }`.

The `Derived(Sprite* sprite)` constructor should pass `sprite` to the parent constructor like this: `Derived(Sprite* sprite): Base(sprite) {};`

Note that as things stand the `Base` constructor *must* be passed a valid `Sprite*` from the `Derived` constructor for `getLocation()` to work on instances of `Derived`.

Comment: You need to address the other problems with Sprite* if you are posting an answer. At least mention rule of three, please. :)

Comment: I initialized the sprite in base class, this is the general moving object. In derived class, which is player class, I also defined the sprite class, but not through base class constructor, I just call sprite constructor like in base class. Does it matters?

Comment: @ohmygoddess, yes, because when you call `getLocation()` it will only see the the `Sprite* sprite` of the `Base` class. So doing things like you did them means it will simply never see and therefore never use the one you created for your `Derived` instance.

Comment: @KennyOstrom and that is why I'm a bit reluctant to go into rule of three right now as there seems to be a more basic issue of "hang on, which members are visible in which context/function" going on. Rule of three is the next step, although a private/ deleted copy constructor may be more appropriate...

Comment: so in this case, if I declare and define sprite class different than base class, then I cannot call method getWidth? because there is no 'base' class sprite, just 'derived' class sprite?

Comment: No way to tell.  We don't know if you initialized all your sprite pointers.  We don't know if they are still valid. The relevant code wasn't posted, so the problem does not occur in the posted example.